# Haskell - Finding Divisors of an Integer

Tags: list, haskell, integer

According to the book this is how its done, but I am not able to get this to work. It gives me an error Not in scope: 'ld'. I'm guessing I should be importing some package but not sure which one. Also the book uses GS module at the prompt but I'm using WinGHCi that has Prelude. What am I missing here?

```
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors n | n < 1 = error "not positive"
          | n == 1 = []
          | otherwise = p : factors (div n p)
                        where p = ld n
```

I guess this can also be done using map and filter functions? How?

Comment: You should rephrase your question to make it clear what issue exactly you're having, so that we can give you appropriate hints.

Comment: Still not very good. Consider divisors first. What does the result of divisors n represent? How would you go about calculating them by hand? Could you translate this into Haskell code? Partially?

Comment: So 1 would be a prime number? What kind of definition is that?

Comment: where does it say 1 is a prime number?

Comment: It doesn't. Niklas must be confused. :-) Edit: I'm wrong. It should say EXCEPT 1. Niklas is not confused.

Comment: Sure it does: "A prime number n is a number whose only divisors are 1 and n". `n=1` is divisible by 1, by `n` (which in this case is equal to 1) and by nothing else. So by that definition 1 would be a prime number.

Comment: @Ingo I think in that case the student would be an idiot to do just that. Unlike them I am not like that. I do my research, find good help and learn and then write my own solution.

Comment: @Sarah I just rephrased the question.

Comment: `ld` is not a library function, perhaps you misspelled, or perhaps your book also provides the definition of `ld`? If it is homework, it would be wise to check with your prof and see which way he wants you to implement it.

Comment: @iPC - if you would provide a sound solution in english, I am sure people here would be happy to translate it to Haskell. But the problem is, apparently, that you have not the slightest idea what "k divides n" *means*.

Comment: @Dan http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/lm2005/GSWH.pdf What should be used instead?

Comment: @iPC it is very funny that the solution you are looking for is on page 5 of the document you mention. Which means, you didn't even bother to read it.

Comment: I did read it @Ingo, my question was what is ld and why is it giving the error not in scope.

Comment: @iPC - Just look at the top of page 5. What do you see there?

Comment: I'll answer the second one and say that it tells you it's not in scope because it's not a standard library function, therefore *you* have to define it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose the aim of the assignment is to teach you about list comprehensions, `filter` and similar constructs, and not to have you write functions that test for primality or create the list of divisors in any sensible way. Therefore what you need is a predicate `divides`,

```
divides :: Int -> Int -> Bool
a `divides` b = ???
```

Then you use that predicate for the argument to `filter` or in a list comprehension to find the list of divisors, and use the `divisors` function for your `isPrime` test.

Answer (score 5):

You want to inspect all numbers from 1 to n, and keep them only if they divide n. The `filter` function can help you:

```
divisors n = filter ??? [1..n]
```

So what condition you need to put in place of `???` ?

For the `isPrime` function you could reuse the `divisors` function, you already mentioned how.

Answer (score 3):

Break it down into simpler steps.

Write a function, `divides :: Int -> Int -> Bool` such that

```
x `divides` n
```

is true when x is a divisor of n.  So, first, think about what it means for `x` to be a divisor of `n`.

Now that you have a way to check if a single number `x` is a divisor of `n`, you need to check a certain range of numbers less than `n` to see which ones are divisors.

Hint: In Haskell, you can generate a list of numbers from 1 to `n` like so: `[1..n]`

This is where that `filter` function you mention would be useful.  Check its type:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Just replace the `a` above with `Int`.

As far as the `isPrime` function, just think about what it means for a number to be prime... if you've calculated your divisors correctly, you can check the list to make sure that it matches with that property.

If this *is* a homework related question, you should definitely tag it with homework, then people don't feel as timid about helping out :)