# Haskell filter function error

Tags: haskell

I want to list all integers that divide n. This is a homework question. So far I have done this.

```
divisors :: Int -> [Int]
divisors n | n < 1 = []
           | otherwise = filter (\n -> n `mod` x == 0) [1..n]
             where x = [1..n]
```

I know this is wrong, but I am not getting the right filter predicate. I don't know how the syntax is for doing this. and ofcourse I cannot use n `mod` n since that is just lists all elements 1 to n.

Comment: Did you not just post a question regarding this?

Comment: no that was a different question on how to use the filter syntax. this is a more specific question and I was suggested to ask a new one for this. sorry.

Comment: A similar post was written a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701662/haskell-finding-divisors-of-an-integer

Comment: i read that post, could not find a solution for my question in it. but it has good tips though.

Comment: Here `n` is a free argument of the function `divisors`, but it should be a bound variable inside the lambda expression that you pass to `filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to check if `mod n k == 0` for each `k` from 1 to `n`. The `n` is fixed (the argument of `divisors`) and the `k` varies, i.e. that is what should be the argument of the lambda expression

```
| otherwise = filter (\k -> n `mod` k == 0) [1 .. n]
```

Comment: Yes! that worked. n is fixed but k varies, I just had to use \k in the predicate definition. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but the type of `mod` is

```
mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

You call it with an Integral argument and a list of integral arguments.